# How to import 70 MB size sql file at phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have one sql file whose size is 70 MB, I am trying to import it at phpmyadmin side but it is giving me connection timed out error.

I have changed below the configuration in php.ini file, but still it is giving me same error. and I am using XAMPP for windows.

post_max_size = 750M

upload_max_filesize = 750M

max_execution_time = 5000

max_input_time = 5000

memory_limit = 1000M

Please help me.

Comment: have you re-started all the services of XAMPP after making above updates? What is import size showing in phpmyadmin at File to import?

Comment: If you have the appropriate access rights, then save the file to the server and use load data infile command to import it.

Comment: With bigger imports, you're probably better off using a different tool than phpMyAdmin. Say, run it from the command line. Do you know how?

Comment: import it from command mode .its far more faster

Comment: No I don't know how execute sql file from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xampp and open the XAMPP Shell .
use below command from your XAMPP shell .
go to command line

```
mysqldump -u {username for DB}  -p  {db_name} > name_for_DB_dump.sql
```

hit enter and you will be prompted to enter password.
enter the password for mysql and db will be imported to sql file with the given name
Please remove curly brackets and text inside them with the relevant information .
Check the XAMPP directory displayed in shell and you will be able to find the sql backup there